failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec, command execution failed, CreateProcess error=193
I am trying to run a spring-boot maven project in local environment.
Build is failing due to error.
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (spec1) on project abc-xyz-service: Command execution failed.: Cannot run program "...\abc-xyz-service\script\generate.sh" (in directory "...\abc-xyz-service"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

The application was built using macOs and I am now trying to run in Windows
Here is pom.xml with plugin block.
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generatedCode</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/java</source>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/src/main/java/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

generate.sh file looks like this:
#!/bin/bash

sdkVersion="1.24.2"

# Download and unzip OpenAPI specs in yaml format
url="https://<some file path>/$sdkVersion.tgz"
generatedFolder=./script/generated
rm -rf $generatedFolder && mkdir -p $generatedFolder
curl -XGET $url -o $generatedFolder/abc-connect-sdk.tgz
tar zxf $generatedFolder/gcc-connect-sdk.tgz -C $generatedFolder

How do I fix this issue?
Please let me know if more information required. I can provide details.
